# Function to grab only values in json as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

If I had a json *object* that looks like this:

```
var json = {
  red: 1,
  blue: 2,
  green: 3
}
```

and would like to get two arrays, one of the keys [red, blue, green] and one for the values [1, 2, 3] without manually creating a forloop, is it possible?

I've done some research and found that Object.keys(json) gets back an array of the keys, but have not been able to find anything for values!

-edit- If an explanation can be provided as to *why* it has been marked as duplicate, I've quite clearly specified I'd prefer a method not to use forloops, that would be nice.

Comment: There's no JSON in this question. What you have in that code block is an object. JSON is a string format.

Comment: If you don't want loop use a library, because someone has to loop through your json. You can use http://underscorejs.org/#keys and http://underscorejs.org/#values

Comment: The duplicate question includes answers that at least explicitly do not do looping; as Mritunjay pointed out, A) something has to, and B) libraries exist that can do it (the answer also indicates that ecma2017 will have this as a native action)